# Manipulando Gradient CSS

Tags: html, css, css3

Estou com um gradient para fazer, com uma divisão de 5 cores e no intervalo de cada uma, tem que ser exatamente dividido.

Segue imagem do que preciso fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu consegui fazer com CSS:

```css
.area{
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  position: relative;
}
.area::before {
background: linear-gradient(to right, #e1202d 0%, #ef8e3b 25%, #075f20 50%, #001a42 75%, #023e79 100%);
content: '';
position: absolute;
height: 6px;
top: 0;
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="area">
Hello world
</div>
```

A dúvida é, como tiro esse gradiente na divisão de cores e deixo exatamente como na imagem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar assim, determinando o o range de início e término da cor:

```css
.area{
 width: 100%;
 padding: 10px 0;
 position: relative;
}
.area::before{
 background-image:linear-gradient(
  to right,
  #e1202d 20%,
  #ef8e3b 20%,
  #ef8e3b 40%,
  #075f20 40%,
  #075f20 60%,
  #001a42 60%,
  #001a42 80%,
  #023e79 80%
 );
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 height: 6px;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>teste</title>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="area">
  Hello World!
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```